# Doubt on an answer to a mechanics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, spring

Question: A block of Mass $m$ is connected to another block of mass $M$ by a massless spring of spring constant $k$ . The blocks are kept on a smooth horizontal plane and are at rest. The spring is unstretched when a constant force $F$ starts acting on the block of mass $M$ (horizontally) to pull it. Find the maximum extension of the spring.
[image: figure]
I solved it by two different methods:

**Method 1:**

Here I assumed that maximum extension $x$ will be produced when both the blocks would be moving with constant acceleration. Therefore constant acceleration is:

$$a=\frac{F}{m+M}\tag{1}$$

and by considering free body diagram of block with mass $m$

$$kx=ma \tag{2}$$

From 1 and 2,
$$\\x=m\frac{F}{k(m+M)}$$

**Method 2:**

By conservation of energy, in the reference frame of center of mass , for block $m$, we have two forces acting $m\frac{F}{m+M}$ and $kx$, in opposite directions.

For block $M$ we have three forces acting $\frac{MF}{m+M}$ and $kx$, and $F$ in the opposite direction.

Assuming $m$ moves a max distance $x_1$ from centre of mass(COM) and M moves a distance $x_2$ from COM, then work done by external force will be:

$$W=\frac{mF(x_1+x_2)}{(m+M)}$$

This will be stored as the internal energy, therefore

$$\frac{1}{2}k(x_1+x_2)^2=W$$

On solving this we get,

$$x_1+x_2=\frac{2mF}{(k(m+M))}$$

Which one is the wrong and why?

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: but first one is correct definitely.

Comment: I'd say the first method is wrong since there is nothing to suggest that maximum extension of spring would occur when acceleration of both blocks are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1 is correct.  The error in Method 2 enters with your expression for "work done by external force".  This should be a sum of the the work done on $m,$ which is $x_1mF/(m+M)$ and that done on $M,$ which is $x_2(F-MF/(m+M))$.  To solve using this method, you will also need an additional relation: the ratio of $x_1$ to $x_2$, which is just $M/m.$ In your expression you are assuming that the work done on the spring is the total length by which it is stretched multiplied by the ultimate tension.  But the tension in the spring only reaches that value at the end of the stretching phase, so the work is only half as much.

Comment: The force F is constant. So why would the tension reach the value at the end of stretching phase?